# Powershell function Params getting unexpected values when CSV fields are not present

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am writing a PowerShell function which can take pipeline input. Specifically I am testing it with `Import-CSV`. Many of the params are not mandatory, which means sometimes the CSV will not have those columns. For boolean values this is working as expected, but with string values, a missing CSV field yields a copy of the row object in the string field.

Here is an example problem parameter:

```
[Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
       ValueFromPipeline=$True,
       ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True,
       HelpMessage="TCP Port of the remote server")]
[Alias('Port', 'Remote Server Port')]
[string]$RemoteServerPort = "5500",
```

Now, if the field is missing, I would expect the value to be `"5500"` as specified, but instead I get:

```
$RemoteServerPort = @{Name=KG; IP=10.1.1.1; Username=Admin; Password=}
```

I've done some looking around, but frankly I'm not even sure what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you specified `ValueFromPipeline=$True` so that PoSh coerces the piped object to a `string` if it cannot bind the parameter by property name. You could solve that by removing `ValueFromPipeline=$True` from this parameter and introduce another one to be bound to the piped object, i.e. something like this

```
function MyTestFunc() {

    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [object]$PipedObj,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False,
               ValueFromPipelinebyPropertyName=$True,
               HelpMessage="TCP Port of the remote server")]
        [Alias('Port', 'Remote Server Port')]
        [string]$RemoteServerPort = "5500"
    )

    Write-Host "Port: $RemoteServerPort / Obj: $PipedObj"
}


$o1 = [pscustomobject]@{"Server" = "123"; "Port" = "12345"}
$o2 = [pscustomobject]@{"Server" = "1234"; "OS" = "Win3.1"}

$o1 | MyTestFunc
$o2 | MyTestFunc
```

Will result in

```
Port: 12345 / Obj: @{Server=123; Port=12345}
Port: 5500 / Obj: @{Server=1234; OS=Win3.1}
```

A way to see in detail what is actually happening behind the scenes is to use `Trace-Command` like so

```
Trace-Command ParameterBinding {$o2 | MyTestFunc} -PSHost
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and got the same result. $RemoteServerPort is still displaying the object string instead of "5500".

Comment: So, I had ValueFromPipeline=$True on a basically all the properties which I now commented out, leaving on the $PipedObj you suggested and it seems like it worked. I need to do a bit more testing though. Do you know why this would be the case?

Comment: Well I guess in that case the whole binding process is confused - [there](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/05/07/tips-on-implementing-pipeline-support/) is a blog post about handling pipeline input and there is also mentioned about weird things happening in such edge cases. If one thinks about it, it doesn't make sense to have `ValueFromPipeline=$True`  for multiple parameters of the same type as PoSh don't know to which parameter the pipeline input should be bound to in this case

Comment: DAX, thanks so much for your help, I'm not sure I would have solved this one on my own. I have read about the param attributes before and I think the naming and descriptions of the two pipeline parameters are pretty confusing. I'll dig into that article, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped